# Writing to AF_LOCAL socket on Mac OS X from shell script

Tags: macos, sockets, shell

I have a Mac OS X app that creates an AF_LOCAL socket (/tmp/app.sock). Is there a way to write to this type of socket from a shell script? I've tried the obvious ("echo xxx > /tmp.app.sock") and some less obvious ("exec 3 <> /tmp/app.sock"), but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. Is there a trick to this, or should I just bite the bullet and write a few lines of C or Java to do what I need? Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably need the C/Java, as shell redirections basically only do `fopen()` stuff, while you need `connect()` stuff for UNIX sockets.

Comment: There's no such functionality built into bash, but you can use netcat instead of those few lines of C or Java.

Answer (score 1):

[Netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) is your friend.

```
echo xxx | nc -U /tmp/app.sock
```

To test that this works, first open another terminal and type this:

```
nc -lU /tmp/app.sock
```

Then go back to your first terminal and run the first command again.

Note that most documentation around the internet is either for [original (Hobbit) netcat](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/) or [GNU Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/), not BSD netcat. But it's not that different, and the manpage should help you deal with most of the differences.

Anything you can't figure out how to do with netcat, try [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) (which is sadly not built in on the Mac, but is easy to install via Homebrew or MacPorts or manually).